# Subscribing to Amazon aws iot mqtt

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, aws-iot

I'm trying to subscribe to mqtt broker in aws.

For subscribing i'm using mosquitto client (Ver  1.4.11).

Command goes like this

```
mosquitto_sub.exe --cafile "path_to_ca" --cert "path_to_cert" --key "path_to_key" -h id1234.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -d -t '$aws/things/DeviceTokyo/shadow/get' -i DeviceTokyoCMD
```

But I'm getting the following response

```
Client DeviceTokyoCMD sending CONNECT
Error: The connection was lost.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the issue.There was something wrong with the policy resource ARN. So I made the change allowing to accept it from anywhere as `*`